# how to change minikube VM ip address with hyperkit driver

Tags: minikube, hyperkit

When starting up minikube with hyperkit driver on MacOS, is there a way to specify the ip address prefix used by the minikube VM? The default ip address of minikube hyperkit VM is 192.168.64.0/24. This address range conflicts with the office ip address and I would like to change it. However, I did not find documentation on how to config that.

Comment: How is configure your Minikube and what full command do you use to run? If you run Minikube what error does it give? It is important to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to specify the ip address prefix used by the minikube VM?

It can't be done with a command or edit the config file.

These IPs are distributed by the vmnet service in the MacOS operating system and are in the file `com.apple.vmnet.plist`. Editing it doesn't change anything.
Editing `/var/db/dhcpd_lease` does not change the IP either. You can read more about this problem on official [Minikube site](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/hyperkit/#local-dns-server-conflict):

> If you are using dnsmasq and minikube fails, add listen-address=192.168.64.1 to dnsmasq.conf.
> If you are running other DNS servers, shut them off or specify an alternative bind address.